# Read line from file, process it, then remove it

Tags: python, readline

I have a 22mb text file containing a list of numbers (1 number per line). I am trying to have python read the number, process the number and write the result in another file. All of this works but if I have to stop the program it starts all over from the beginning. I tried to use a mysql database at first but it was way too slow. I am getting about 4 times the number being processed this way. I would like to be able to delete the line after the number was processed.

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
for line in file:
    filename = line.rstrip('\n') + ".txt"
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        print "File", filename, "exists, skipping!"
    else:
        #process number and write file
    #(need code to delete current line here)
```

As you can see every time it is restarted it has to search the hard drive for the file name to make sure it gets to the place it left off. With 1.5 million numbers this can take a while. I found an example with truncate but it did not work.

Are there any commands similar to array_shift (PHP) for python that will work with text files.

Comment: Are you trying to write each number to a separate file? If so why?

Comment: you could try to use Postgres and pl/pgsql to perform any computation by the database itself...

Comment: Take a look at sqlite, a great fast/simple local file-based DB supported natively by Python: http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: The numbers are unique. The numbers are the file names and each file contains a long calculation with the number along with some json information. The files will be used with a Document-oriented Database like CouchDB or MongoDB.

Answer (score 7):

I would use a marker file to keep the number of the last line processed instead of rewriting the input file:

```
start_from = 0

try:
    with open('last_line.txt', 'r') as llf: start_from = int(llf.read())
except:
    pass

with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        if i < start_from: continue

        filename = line.rstrip('\n') + ".txt"
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            print "File", filename, "exists, skipping!"
        else:
            pass
        with open('last_line.txt', 'w') as outfile: outfile.write(str(i))
```

This code first checks for the file last_line.txt and tries to read a number from it. The number is the number of line which was processed in during the previous attempt. Then it simply skips the required number of lines.

Comment: +1, Good answer - you could remove the `i+=1` part by taking advantage of [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: It's worth checking what the use-case is where it stops in the middle. Doing a file write on every line is going to end up being where you spend most of your time. If there are no cases where you stop in the middle, it'd be better to account for those explicitly and not do thousands of needless file writes. If your program just randomly gets killed, it's still probably better to only do the write every 100 or 1000 lines.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't this solution skip over the first line? On the first pass through the loop, we iterate i so that it's greater than 0 - so the first line that is actually read is line 1, not line 0 isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I use Redis for stuff like that. Install redis and then pyredis and you can have a persistent set in memory. Then you can do:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis('localhost')
with open('list.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if r.sismember('done', line):
            continue
        else:
            #process number and write file
            r.sadd('done', line)
```

if you don't want to install Redis you can also use the shelve module, making sure that you open it with the writeback=False option. I really recommend Redis though, it makes things like this so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the data file should not be a bottleneck. The following code read a 36 MB, 697997 line text file in about 0,2 seconds on my machine:

```
import time

start = time.clock()
with open('procmail.log', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
end = time.clock()
print 'Readlines time:', end-start
```

Because it produced the following result:

```
Readlines time: 0.1953125
```

Note that this code produces a list of lines in one go.

To know where you've been, just write the number of lines you've processed to a file. Then if you want to try again, read all the lines and skip the ones you've already done:

```
import os

# Raad the data file
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

skip = 0
try:
    # Did we try earlier? if so, skip what has already been processed
    with open('lineno.txt', 'r') as lf:
        skip = int(lf.read()) # this should only be one number.
        del lines[:skip] # Remove already processed lines from the list.
except:
    pass

with open('lineno.txt', 'w+') as lf:
    for n, line in enumerate(lines):
        # Do your processing here.
        lf.seek(0) # go to beginning of lf
        lf.write(str(n+skip)+'\n') # write the line number
        lf.flush()
        os.fsync() # flush and fsync make sure the lf file is written.
```

Comment: I think there's a bug in this code. You're not updating `list.txt` but `lines` is updated (lines[:skip]) and enumerated over.
One fix would be to write `lines` to `list.txt` before enumerating over `lines`. I'll add it to your solution.

Comment: @MikaeilOrfanian Not updating `list.txt` is done *on purpose*. The original poster does not specify he wants to update it.

Comment: I understand, you're right! I missed the `n+skip` when you write the counter to file. I thought you were writing only the `n` to file.