# In python, how would I delete a line in a file if query matches a result

Tags: python

I have a text file with a list of values that I need to query against in MySQL. If the result from the query returns 1 or more rows, i need to delete the line from the file. I will run the query until the file is empty.

```
# cat file.txt
bob
susan
jeff
mary

# cat script.py
f = open('file.txt')
for line in f:
    # mysql query to get 'query_result'
    if query_result == 1:
        # do some work
        # proceed to delete the value from the file
```

Comment: Check here for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678146/python-read-line-from-file-process-it-then-remove-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the with open syntax (it will close your file for you):

```
fileLines = []
with open('field.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # mysql query to get 'query_result'
        if query_result != 1:
            fileLines.append(line) # These will be the lines you actually want

with open('field.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in fileLines:
        f.write(line)
```

This will essentially rewrite the whole file. So be careful with it, if you query frequently, you will probably want to load the file lines and make temp changes, periodically updating the file. You might also want to load the temp data into a temp file for persistence.

Comment: This adds the line i don't want back into the file.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the file isn't necessary. I think it's ok to just do this:

```
f = open('file.txt')
lines = f.readlines()
deleted = set()
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line in deleted:
        continue
    # do query
    if query_result == 1:
        deleted.add(line)
```